# Floating-point error when not assigned to a float variable

Tags: c#

I have the static method `GetFraction` which returns the cents in a price as below:

```
public static class PriceUtil
{
    public static int GetFraction(float price)
    {
        int PriceInt = (int)(100 * price);

        return PriceInt % 100;
    }
}
```

For the price $23.79, this method returns 78 Cents instead of 79. While debugging, I fixed the bug unintentionally as follows:

```
public static class PriceUtil
{
    public static int GetFraction(float price)
    {
        float PriceFloat = 100 * price;
        int PriceInt = (int)(PriceFloat);

        return PriceInt % 100;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why assigning the (100 * price) to a float variable solves the problem. AFAIK, casting to integer is applied to exactly same value as `int` times `float` is `float` anyways.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: I would use a decimal variable for this purpose. Money is a place where even tiny fractions are important, which does not work well with floats.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake; checking in the debugger yields a value of 79 for an argument of `23.79f` in both implementations of the function. Check here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/d9qNuW However, I totally second the suggstion to use `Decimal` for this purpose, not `float`.

Comment: In your second example, the only int you ever see is your result from the `%` operator. In the first example, you cast your product (`float * 100`) to an int, then get the `%` from it. It's most like a floating point error. Generally speaking, to avoid these, keep your numbers as decimals unless you **require** integer values.

Comment: As to the why, bear in mind that implementations of the CLR are allowed to use larger types for floating point calculations, and may therefore perform truncation when you force an assignment to a variable.

Comment: @ChristianSauer, Flater and Codor: Thank you for pointing a better type for storing price. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been noted in the comments you should be using `decimal` as the type instead of `float` to avoid this kind of problem.

Using the value `23.79f` does not exhibit the problem you describe on my computer so my guess is that the price has been computed by some previous calculation. Here is a demonstration:

```
var value = 23.7899999f;
Console.WriteLine(value);
var fraction = ((int) (value*100))%100;
Console.WriteLine(fraction);
```

The output of this code is

```
23.79
78
```

Another possibility of the problem you experience is that `float` is a 32 bit floating point number and internally on the CPU calculations are often performed using 80 bit floating point numbers. If you change the way you perform your calculations you may see slightly different results depending on when the rounding or truncation is performed. However, I doubt that this is the explanation of the results that you experience.

You should be able to solve your problem by rounding the value before computing the fraction:

```
var value = 23.7899999f;
Console.WriteLine(value);
var roundedValue = Math.Round(value, 2);
var fraction = ((int) 100*roundedValue)%100;
Console.WriteLine(fraction);
```

The output is now

```
23.79
79
```

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Martin Liversage: Both explanations seem to point to the same reason that internal calculations use higher number of bits. Maybe that's why assigning it to an `int` variable helped me rounding the number. I will keep that in mind and make sure that I cast/round values before passing them to anything else.